# Check either its a char or an integer

Tags: c, char, int

this is an integer array:

```
int values[] = { 75, '*', 5,'-' };

for(i=0 ; i<size ; i++){
    // Here
}
```

how to check if the ***`values[i]`*** is an integer or an operation ??

maybe the value equals the Ascii of an operation,, how to deal with it in this case??

Comment: '-' is operation and 45 as integer at the same time

Comment: ok, but how could I know its 45 or '-' ??

Comment: You cann't. When you have both `'-'` & `45`, ascii value of `-` is stored in the array. So, there are two `45`, and you cann't differentiate between the two. Also, there is a typo in the question. `values` should be an array.

Comment: You should ask about your _real_ problem. Presumably you're parsing some input, in which case both the numbers and operators are in the form of a sequence of characters and can be distinguished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a dangerous road to go down.  The array in your example will translate (during compilation) into:

```
int values[] = {75, 42, 5, 45};
```

So when you see the number 42... what is it?  Is it the `'*'` character, or did you actually mean the number `42`?

You can't rely on typecasting, either, because all your values will be cast to `int`s, since they're stored in an integer array.  Your best bet is to make a struct that holds both type and value, like so:

```
typedef struct
{
    int type;  //0 for int, 1 for operator, and so forth.
    int value; //holds either a character code or an integer value
    //you could use a union here, if you felt it would make things cleaner...
} Token;
```

Then checking to see what type a token is is simply a matter of looking at `token.type`.

Hope this helps!

**PS:**  The cheating answer would be to use a dynamically typed language.  Lots less work on your part, but slower, and I don't know if it's an option for you.

Answer (score 8):

You can't.  As for as the compiler is concerned, the constants `42` an `'*'` are one and the same.  In the compiled object code, they're both represented as the integer 42.

If you need to differentiate between integers and characters, either use a boolean flag or enum indicating the type of the value, or keep your integers and characters in separate arrays.

Note that in C++, but *not* in C, there is a slight difference: `42` has the type `int`, whereas `'*'` has the type `char`, so you can differentiate this fact using overloaded functions or templates.

Comment: I can't !!,, you mean there is no way to get around it ?? in C

Comment: @Rami: The way to get around it is to redesign your code.  Don't use an array of `int`, use a more complicated structure that contains the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your array elements cannot be simple integers.
Try this instead:

```
enum ElementType {INTEGER, OPERATION};
struct ArrayElement {
    enum ElementType etype;
    int evalue;
};
struct ArrayElement values[] = {
    {INTEGER, 75}, {OPERATION, '*'}, {INTEGER, 5}, {OPERATION, '-'}
};

for (i = 0; i < sizeof values / sizeof *values; i++) {
    /* Here */
    switch (values[i].etype) {
        default: printf("unrecognized type. value is %d.\n", values[i].value);
                 break;
        case INTEGER: printf("INTEGER with value %d.\n", values[i].value);
                      break;
        case OPERATION: printf("OPERATION with value '%c'.\n", values[i].value);
                        break;
    }
}
```